# Angular - adding multiple controllers prompts [$controller:ctrlreg] error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this is something small, but this is my first time using angular and the other answers around this question were regarding each controller file separately while my issue is regarding importing my JavaScript file in my HTML page.

Simply, I have two controller files:

> Controller1.js
>
> Controller2.js

In my HTML file it looks like this (**problem is this snippet here**):

```
 <!-- Import our angular controller -->
 <script src="Controller1.js"></script>
 <script src="Controller2.js"></script>
```

and is used in this manner:

```
    <!-- the ng-app is in the body... -->
    <div ng-controller="Controller1">
    </div>
```

**Note: I am simply using ONE controller in my code**, and just manually changing the controller name depending on the example I wish to demonstrate. I do not need both controllers on separate elements or running at the same time.

And each controller is set up as such:

```
 angular.module('theAppName', [])
    .controller('Controller1', function($scope) 

and    

angular.module('theAppName', [])
    .controller('Controller2', function($scope) {
```

The problem I have is that when I simply import the single controller script I am using in my HTML file, it works fine. However if I import both of the controllers even if I am not using one it breaks. Can I import multiple controllers if I do not want to use one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inject the 2nd controller , you do not have to pass the empty dependencies, it should be as

```
angular.module('theAppName')
    .controller('Controller2', function($scope) {
}
```